# error with lapply on anonymous ggplot function

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to use lapply on an ggplot anonymous function

```
if (inputMethodP=="WITHINFILE")
                    {
                        par(mfrow=c(5,listPortions))
                            plotList<-lapply(RangeStatResultP, function(listPart)
                        {


                                ggplot(matrixPart, aes(x = factor(Var2), y=value)) + geom_violin()+
                                ggtitle(names(listPart)+xlab(listnum)+ylab("Coverage")+
                                stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = "point", position = position_dodge(width = .9),
                                size = 6, shape = 4, show_guide = F)
                        })


                    }
```

when ever I insert this chunk of code into my script it gives
me the error

```
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"                                         size = 6, shape = 4, show_guide = F)
    }"
```

Is my syntax wrong? I can't seem to hunt down whatever stray { is causing this.

Comment: add one more closed parantheses after `show_guide = F)` to close up the `ggtitle` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a paranthesis to close `ggtitle()` as `names()` also requires a closing paren.

```
if (inputMethodP == "WITHINFILE") {
  par(mfrow = c(5, listPortions))
  plotList <- lapply(RangeStatResultP, function(listPart) {
    ggplot(matrixPart, aes(x = factor(Var2), y = value)) +
      geom_violin()+
      ggtitle(names(listPart)) +
      xlab(listnum) +
      ylab("Coverage") +
      stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = "point",
                   position = position_dodge(width = .9), size = 6, shape = 4,
                   show_guide = F)
  })
}
```